# Why is multiprocessing.Pool slower with large number of items

Tags: image, multiprocessing, pool

I'm using a multiprocessing.Pool along with apply_async() to process a large number of images (around 1000).

I've set the pool to use 4 processes.

My issue is with how the rate of processed images changes depending on the number of items to be processed.

For example, when the pool is filled with 10 items, those items are processed in 0.5 seconds.

When the same code is run on 1000 items, the first 10 items are processed in 10 seconds.

Why is this? I'd expect the length to do the whole job to increase, but not the rate at which the images are processed.

Here's the code:

```
imagelist = [...] # array of images(pixel data)
pool = Pool(processes=4)
for i, image in enumerate(imagelist):
    a = pool.apply_async(process, args=(image), callback=postprocess)
```

I'd expect the rate of images processed to be constant, no matter the number of items being processed. Why is it not?

Comment: I am no expert but I would say this : You start the process for all of them so the processor switches much more between each thread, leaving less time for your actual process to run
I don't know what your process consist of but be sure that it either run long-time running calculation or some blocking process (like download or something). Otherwise it is not that useful

Comment: @DimitriBosteels The process is an image processing function using OpenCV. It normally takes around a second or two to complete. Do you think that's too fast?

Comment: no but then why does it take less than 1 second for 10 images if it takes 1 to 2 seconds per process
But it is normal if you check only the runtime for the first items. Asynchronous programming is less effective when the collection is small. So compare the running time for the whole collection instead :) 
Well a simple way to check if it is faster is to do it asynchronously and synchronously, with a timer and check the elapsed time for one or the other.

Comment: Is the size of the images the same for each image or does it change from image to image?

Comment: @DimitriBosteels Will try timing it

Comment: @noxdafox They're all the same size